# Google One Tap SignIn with Azure B2C, .NET Core and Blazor Webassembly

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-active-directory, blazor-webassembly, google-identity

I'm currently using Azure B2C as identity management server to give my Blazor Webassembly client access to a .NET core API, but find the sign in flow to be a bit clunky. I've looked at [Google One Tap sign in](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web) which is much more smooth but I'm not sure if that can be integrated with Azure B2C or if I need to throw that out. Can Google One Tap signin be incorporated Azure B2C and what are the basic steps to do so? And if that is not possible what are my alternatives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can configure Azure AD B2C to allow users to sign in to your application with credentials from external identity providers like Facebook, Google and GitHub.

Google One Tap is part of Google Identity Service, it's a type of Google Authentication without using password and we can use Google Identity Service along side with Azure AD B2C.

- First we need to to register Google as an identity provider for your Azure AD B2C tenant, as described in this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-google?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).
- You need to create a sign-up or sign-in policy, as described at [Azure Active Directory B2C: Built-in policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-policies#create-a-sign-up-or-sign-in-policy), and add **Google** as an **identity provider** for this policy.

Check this example of using [Google Identity Provider with Azure AD B2C](https://thecodeblogger.com/2020/05/17/google-identity-provider-with-azure-ad-b2c/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you. I've followed these steps previously and added google as an external identity provider to my Azure AD B2C tenant. And I've added a sign up and sign in policy with google as identity provider. 

But it doesn't seem like that flow can be integrated with the Google One Tap flow. I can get a jwt token from the google one tap but I'm guessing that won't help to automatically register and sign the user into Azure B2C. 

I decided to switch stack to React + Firebase, it seems to fit better.